# multiple variable in python regex

Tags: python-3.x

I have seen several related posts and several forums to find an answer for my question, but nothing has come up to what I need.

I am trying to use variable instead of hard-coded values in regex which search for either word in a line.

However i am able to get desired result if i don't use variable.

```
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub/a1#Msoffice>
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub1/a1#vlc>
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub2/a2#dell>
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub3/a3#Notepad>

re.search(r"\#Msoffice|#vlc|#Notepad", line)
```

This regex will return the line which has `#Msoffice` OR `#vlc` OR `#Notepad`.

I tried defining a single variable using re.escape and that worked absolutely fine. However i have tried many combination using | and , (pipe and comma) but no success.

Is there any way i can specify `#Msoffice` , `#vlc` and `#Notepad` in different variables and so later i can change those ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understand you the right way you'd like to insert variables in your regex.

You are actually using a raw string using `r' '` to make the regex more readable, but if you're using `f' '` it allows you to insert any variables using `{your_var}` then construct your regex as you like:

```
var1 = '#Msoffice'
var2 = '#vlc'
var3 = '#Notepad'

re.search(f'{var1}|{var2}|{var3}', line)
```

The most annoying issue is that you will have to add `\` to escaped char, to look for `\` it will be `\\`

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

lines = ["<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub/a1#Msoffice>", 
                "<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub1/a1#vlc>",
                "<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub2/a2#dell>",
                "<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub3/a3#Notepad>"]

for line in lines:
    if re.search(r'\b(?:\#{}|\#{}|\#{})\b'.format('Msoffice', 'vlc', 'Notepad'), line): 
        print(line)
```

Output :

```
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub/a1#Msoffice>
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub1/a1#vlc>
<http://www.somesite.com/software/sub3/a3#Notepad>
```